Apparent paradox in general relativity wrt relative gravity, spacetime curvature and time dilation
Imagine Alice is near a massive black hole and Bob is on the Earth.
Obviously their gravitational fields are different for each other. In other words, their spacetime is flat for themselves but curved for each other. Bob sees spacetime of Alice is curved. And Alice sees spacetime of Bob is curved. Thus time should run slower for each other.
However, in reality it is said that from Alice's point of view Bob's time is running faster, and from Bob's point of view Alice's time is running slower.
If this is true, how can we say that gravity is relative?
Update:
Based upon questions asked in comments. Here is update:
Both Alice and Bob will agree that spacetime is more curved in Alice's vicinity. Thus Speed of one clock (because of it's gravity) can be measured regardless of gravity of the observer. Unlike velocity, which is dependent of velocity of observer, because velocity is relative.
Gravity is not relative to observer's gravity. Why do we say that gravity is relative?

You have a number of misconceptions here. Firstly curvature is not relative in the way you suggest - both Alice and Bob will agree that spacetime is more curved in Alice's vicinity - and secondly time dilation is not simply related to curvature anyway.

You are mixing the twin paradox of Kinetic Time Dilation in Special Relativity with Gravitational Time Dilation in General Relativity.  They are two different things.   Both people would agree that Alice ages slower than Bob.

"Obviously their gravitational fields are different for each other. "  What did you think this means, and what made you think it was obvious?

@foolishmuse Actually yes I am coming from there only. I thought the paradox should exists here as well if gravity is relative just as in velocity is relative.

@WillO I mean, when Bob see gravity is much stronger near black hole than it is on the Earth. For him Alice is in steep curve. That makes obvious by geometry for Alice to see Bob in steep curve.

I don't understand what you think Bob is "seeing", or even what you mean by "see".

Relative means that no matter where you go your clock will always be ticking normally for you. It means that time on your clock cannot be held as a standard in the universe because it is subject to conditions that you cannot measure. Don't you think it's paradox enough that your time can change without you knowing, without involving more than one person?

@WillO "see" in the typical sense how they explain relative velocity and time dilation. "Both parties see clock running slow for other" because speed of both in same wrt each other.  Similarly if Bob sees apple falling faster from the tree near Alice, so the same  Alice too should see. i.e. apple falling faster from the tree near Bob. When falling speed is same for both in their own frame of reference.

Gravity is not relative in the way that speed is relative.   Alice will see that she is on a steep curve compared to distant space, and she will see that Bob is on a lesser curve compared to distant space.  So while she might say that Bob is on a steep curve compared to her, it would be like someone on a ski jump ramp saying that people in the audience on flat land are steep compared to the ramp, but he would understand that it is he who is on the ramp compared to the people on flat land.

@Wookie I understand it fully that clock will always be ticking normally for you. But if "Bob sees Alice's clock is running slower, and Alice sees Bob's clock running faster" then how can we say gravity is relative? If gravity is relative, just as in velocity, it should be like "Bob sees Alice's clock is running slower, and Alice too sees Bob's clock running slower" And that's the point I am trying to make.

@foolishmuse "Gravity is not relative in the way that speed is relative" may be that's what I am unable to comprehend. When we say things are relative to each other, I would expect symmetry, just as they do in relative velocity.

Okay then, let's put the gravity inside the clocks. Alice and Bob are standing beside one another. Alice's clock has dense matter inside, Bob's doesn't. They both see Alice's clock running slower than Bob's.

You say you are using "see" as in the typical sense how they explain relative velocity and time dilation.  That typical sense involves using metersticks, clocks, etc. to measure the locations of a given object at a variety of times (in your preferred coordinate system) and doing some calculations.  I understand what it means to "see" acceleration in that sense, but that still doesn't tell me what you mean by "seeing" gravity or spacetime curvature.    Do you just mean seeing the acceleration due to gravity?  Or something else?

@WillO Seeing bending of the light, acceleration due to gravity, slower speed of atomic clock etc. More is the gravity more are these things. But then if for any reason gravity of blackhole (Alice) increases, the increment will be observed by both Bob and Alice as increment in blockholes' (Alice) gravity. Unlike in case of velocity, increment in one's velocity applicable to relative velocity of both. So my point remains same, how can we say gravity is relative?

@Wookie I got the point you made. Speed of one clock (because of it's gravity) can be observed and told independently. Unlike velocity of object which is dependent of velocity of another object (observer) because velocity is relative. With the of example you given it is clear that gravity is not relative to observer's gravity. That's my question was:  how can we say that gravity is relative?

The time dilation due to the curvature of spacetime is not symmetric between observers in the same way as their relative velocity is.
In Special Relativity, the time dilation factor $\gamma = (1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$ involves the speed. It does not matter whether the velocity is $\pm v$, the time dilation factor is the same. Therefore both observers would claim that the other's clock is running slower.
That symmetry does not apply to the gravitational time dilation that arises from observers being at different positions with respect to a gravitational potential. All that matters here is the (signed) difference in potential and both observers agree that Bob is at a higher potential than Alice and therefore his clock runs relatively more quickly in comparison.

Yes, we don't measure any time dilation except the one between the observers at relative positions to the gravitational potential.

I understand it fully and many thanks for answer. I am still not getting why then gravity is said to be relative entity when time dilation and other effects caused by it can be calculated independently regardless of observers' gravity

@user1976551 Time dilation is relative. You can only compare two clocks. And the difference in their apparent rates depends where the observers are. "All that matters here is the (signed) difference in potential."
